# Update python version in existing virtualenv in ubuntu

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to update the python version in my already existing virtual environment. I installed python using following steps

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/Python-2.7.11.tgz
tar xfz Python-2.7.11.tgz
cd Python-2.7.11/
./configure --prefix /usr/local/lib/python2.7.11 --enable-ipv6
make
sudo make install
```

I checked the version as well and its coming correctly

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.11
```

I have an existing virtualenv named test and I want to use python2.7.11 in this environment. It tried using

```
workon test --python /usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/bin/python
```

But the version of python is shown as the old one only

```
python -V
Python 2.7.6
```

If I create a new environment, it works fine

```
mkvirtualenv test2 -p /usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/bin/python
python -V
Python 2.7.11
```

I tried finding the solution but couldn't figure out how to modify python version in the existing virtual environment.
Any help in figuring out the solution will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The python interpreter in a virtualenv is definitive. But virtual envs are disposable, so I suggest you to create a new one with the good python interpreter.

Comment: I have installed lot of stuff in this virtualenv and my website is running in this virtual env only. I don't want to setup everything again. Is there no way to update python?

Comment: You can easily rebuild it. In the old venv, `pip freeze > /tmp/requirements.txt` save all what you've installed in a single file. In the new virtualenv, `pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt` reinstall everything.

Comment: Its not just installing things, I am running supervisor, celery, flower, django, elastic search etc. Apart from installing them, I will need to setup all the configurations again which I want to avoid.

Comment: Well your virtualenv folder should just be an execution context. In it you should find python/pip/... binaries and libraries. All your code and external parts should be somewhere else.

Comment: Agreed - a virtualenv directory should contain only python and things installed by pip. This is possibly a confusion when people say 'Run things in a virtualenv', and what 'in' means...